# IntelliJ Idea: Where are installed the plugins and configuration settings in Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I installed for Mac (10.11) and Windows 10

- `ideaIC-2020.2.3`

For both, for the first time about their startup process, I selected and configured the custom plugins, such as Gradle, Git Github etc... Then I imported some projects based in Gradle such as `spring-framework` and `spring-integration`.

About Gradle was specified its settings about:

- Gradle custom home directory i.e: 6.7 (therefore there is no a wrapper)

Each Project share a common and custom repository.

Well, due a problem:

- I deleted and reinstalled/unpacked the IDE.
- The 'projects' were imported again (deleted the original directory and re-created that directory and copied/pasted there again the project) and I did realise the settings remains in the IDE.

#### Goal

In the re-install process I want see again the *dialog* where I was able to select the custom plugins at the beginning.

In `Windows 10` I was able to find within the hidden `AppData` directory twice the `JetBrains` directory in two different directories (`Local` and `Roaming`), If I delete both directories. I can accomplish my goal

In MacOS I tried to find something like .jetbrains .idea or .intellij and nothing.

#### Question

Where are located the configurations settings in Mac?

Note: I am a STS/Eclipse user, so I am starting to play with this IDE. I watched some videos about to learn use this IDE, but I have this situation. In STS/Eclipse is enough delete the workspace directory that contains the .metadata hidden directory and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Default IDE directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs) section of the IntelliJ IDEA WebHelp.

There is also the File | Manage Settings | Restore Default Settings... action which will make a back-up copy of your current IDE settings and reset them. So upon restart you will start with defaults.

Comment: Tested the `Default IDE directories` and works perfect. Even in my old Mac. Thanks